# Jquery building multiple timers and .each(function() {

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build multiple timers for my web page, so far I have,

```
$('.timer').each(function() {
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var time = $(this).text().split(':');
    var minutes = parseInt(time[0], 10);
    var seconds = parseInt(time[1], 10);
    // TIMER RUN OUT 
    if (!minutes && !seconds) {
        // CLEAR TIMER
        clearInterval(timer);
    // MINUS SECONDS
    } else {
        seconds -= 1;
    }
    // MINUS MINUTES
    if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
        minutes -= 1;
        seconds = 59;
    // ADD ZERO IF SECONDS LESS THAN 10
    } else {
        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }
    }
    // ADD ZERO IF MINUTES LESS THAN 10
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }
}, 1000);
});
```

This doesn't work though! Where am I going wrong!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, inside your `setInterval` callback, `this` no longer refers to the `.timer` element. Try changing that to `self` and add `var self = this;` before the call to `setInterval`. Second, you never write your time back to your `.timer` element.

Comment: Good answer! Will jquery take care of clearing the correct `clearInterval` if one clock runs out before the other?

Comment: `timer` is fine, just like `self` is. The context of `this` is the only thing that changes in the callback. The `timer` variable itself is contained in a closure in your `.each` callback, so each `.timer` element gets its own variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display a clock counting down? In that case, you're not updating the text after all the calculations. Try adding:

```
$(this).text(minutes+':'+seconds);
```